# Необходимо сравнить два списка [(1,), (2,), (3,)] и [2, 3, 4, 5]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть два списка:

```
old_users = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
current_users = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Необходимо выполнить следующую операцию:

```
res = [x for x in old_users if x in current_users]
outcoming = list(set(old_users) - set(res))
print('Потерянные: ', outcoming)
incoming = list(set(current_users) - set(res))
print('Найденные: ', incoming)
```

**P.S.** Не уверен, что это важно, но рабочий вариант должен поддерживать сравнение сотен тысяч элементов. Стабильность и точность важнее скорости.

**P.S.S.** пробовал сделать их одинаковыми вот так:

```
for i in raw_current_users:
    a = '(' + str(i) + ',)'
    current_users.append(a)
```

Но не получилось

Comment: Какую именно операцию необходимо выполнить и что именно не получилось?

Comment: стопудов, old_users берутся из базы (select id from ,,,), а current_users из группы вк :)

Comment: необходимо сравнить элементы в списках. В результате необходимо получить уникальные элементы, которые находятся только в одном из них. В качестве решения, я нашел общие элементы и вычел их из общего списка

Comment: gil9red 2, именно так они и берутся :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы ваш алгоритм заработал нужно привести списки к одному виду:

```
old_users = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
old_users = [user for (user,) in old_users]  # [1, 2, 3]

current_users = [2, 3, 4, 5]

outcoming = list(set(old_users) - set(current_users))
print('Потерянные:', outcoming)

incoming = list(set(current_users) - set(old_users))
print('Найденные:', incoming)
```

---

Для быстродействия имеет смысл один раз преобразовывать списки в множества:

```
old_users = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
current_users = [2, 3, 4, 5]

old_users = {user for (user,) in old_users}  # {1, 2, 3}
current_users = set(current_users)

outcoming = list(old_users - current_users)
print('Потерянные:', outcoming)

incoming = list(current_users - old_users)
print('Найденные:', incoming)
```

Консоль:

```
Потерянные: [1]
Найденные: [4, 5]
```

---

Дело в том, что у вас списки имели разную структуру:

- `old_users` это `List[Tuple[Int]]`
- `current_users` это `List[Int]`

Когда вы использовали множество, то каждый элемент списка проходил хеширование, а хеши разных объектов (`(1,)` и `1`) отличаются

Comment: мне кажется для данной задачи эффективнее будет один раз (и сразу) преобразовать списки в множества и пребразовывать разницу множеств в список при выводе (если нужен именно список, а не множество)...

Comment: Я видел, что они отличаются, по бряке когда останавливал оба списка были {list}. Но через принт, я видел, в чем дело, а как сравнить не понимал...

Comment: @MaxU, согласен